# entering data in dictionaries within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, user-input

I want to enter data in a dictionary within a dictionary taking input from user. This is my code for it:

```
n= int(raw_input("Enter no of customers:"))

d={}
d1={}
d2={}

for i in range(n):
    print "Enter Details for customer-{}".format(i+1)
    s="Customer-{}".format(i)
    #print s
    #print type(s)
    d1["Name"]=raw_input("Enter Name:")
    d1["Phone"]=long(raw_input("Enter Phone:"))
    d1["Tab"]=float(raw_input("Enter Tab:"))

    d2["Address-1"]=raw_input("Enter Address-1:")
    d2["Address-2"]=raw_input("Enter Address-2:")
    d2["State"]=raw_input("Enter State:")

    d1["Address"]=d2    

    d[s]=d1
    #print d

print d


for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print k

    for k1,v1 in d1.iteritems():
        if k1=="Address":
        print "\tAddress:"

        else:
            print "\t",k1,":",v1

    for k2,v2 in d2.iteritems():
        print "\t\t",k2,":",v2
```

Just the problem I'm facing is it's overriding the data and I'm not able to understand why.

The output is as follows:

```
Customer-1
Phone : 433
Name : ggg
Tab : 433.0
Address:
State : 434
Address-2 : 443
Address-1 : 4343

Customer-0
Phone : 433
Name : ggg
Tab : 433.0
Address:
State : 434
Address-2 : 443
Address-1 : 4343

Customer-2
Phone : 433
Name : ggg
Tab : 433.0
Address:
State : 434
Address-2 : 443
Address-1 : 4343
```

Please, any help is appreciated!

Comment: In addition to Martijn's answer, make sure you iterate over the contents of `v` in the inner for-loop when printing the results. Currently you are looping over `d1`:     `for k1,v1 in d1.iteritems():`

Comment: you mean i should write v instead of d1?? can you please elaborate??

Comment: Yeah got it thanks I iterated over "v" Thanks One more thing to do is If I want to sort the dict according to name I wrote: sorted(d, key=lambda x: (d[x]['Name'],x)) but its not giving correct results Can you please tell y??

Comment: You can try sorting the `iteritems`: `sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Name'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a *new* dictionary in the loop:

```
d={}

for i in range(n):
    d1={}
    d2={}
```

otherwise you keep assigning the same object and change it in the loop over and over again.

You were only storing a *reference* to an existing dictionary in `d`, not a copy. You can create multiple references to a dictionary, and any changes are visible through all those references:

```
>>> foo = {}
>>> bar = foo
>>> foo['eggs'] = 'ham'
>>> bar
{'eggs': 'ham'}
>>> foo['eggs'] = 'spam'
>>> bar
{'eggs': 'spam'}
```

The expression `d[s]=d1` only stores a reference to `d1` under a given key in `d`, and *all* those references point to the same object. By moving the `d1 = {}` and `d2 = {}` lines into the loop, you create *new* dictionaries each iteration.

Another method of ensuring you are creating a reference to a *new* dictionary is by creating a copy of it with the [`dict.copy()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy), but creating a new dictionary here is preferable.

You may want to give your variables better names as well; instead of `d`, `d1` and `d2`, perhaps you want to use `customers`, `customer` and `address` instead.

Comment: I checked it but it is still overiding .. can you tell any other way??

Comment: @user2696258: I guess you didn't yet create the new dictionaries in the correct location or correct name.

Comment: Sorry its  working fine... now but can you tell me the way how to print it using d1 and d2 or without using them because when I'm printing it with loops as done above its overiding but when I just write " print d" output is as expected

Comment: You are looping over the last version of `d1`, not what is in your `d` dictionary; don't reuse those.

Comment: Yeah got it thanks I iterated over "v" Thanks One more thing to do is If I want to sort the dict according to name  I wrote:        sorted(d, key=lambda x: (d[x]['Name'],x))                                 but its not giving correct results Can you please tell y??

Comment: What results did you expect? You could post that as a new question perhaps.